# How can I order a not typed array?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

JSON:

```
"media$thumbnail":[
    {
     "url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/gL23XCv6rek/default.jpg",
     "height":90,
     "width":120,
     "time":"00:08:11",
     "yt$name":"default"
    },
    {
     "url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/gL23XCv6rek/mqdefault.jpg",
     "height":180,
     "width":320,
     "yt$name":"mqdefault"
    },
    {
     "url":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/gL23XCv6rek/hqdefault.jpg",
     "height":360,
     "width":480,
     "yt$name":"hqdefault"
    }
]
```

My code:

```
var thumbnailList = (JArray)item["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"];
```

and I'd like to extract the `"url"` with the max `"width"` value.

I should order this list with `OrderByDescending(p => p.width)`, but of course I can't access to that typed value.

How can I do it? Is there a way on LINQ?

Comment: Can't test right now, but I'd try something like `OrderByDescending(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.SelectToken("width")))`. Error handling not included :)

Comment: Yeah it works :) If you wrote the answer, you get +1 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have getting is a `JArray` that you can enumerate to `JToken`s, and `JToken` has a method `SelectToken` that can get values nested inside of it.

Using Linq, you'd end up with something similar to;

```
OrderByDescending(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.SelectToken("width")))
```